# Better way for writing the reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

Is there a better way for writing the following code:

```
export const getItemsSuccess = (state, entity, payload) => {
  const {count, rows} = payload

  const clonedState = {...state}
  clonedState[entity] = {...clonedState[entity], count, rows}

  return {
    ...clonedState,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple cases like this, I tend to inline this into a single object literal. It makes the logic a bit easier to follow.

```
export const getItemsSuccess = (state, entity, {count, rows}) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    [entity]: {
      ...state[entity],
      count,
      rows,
    }
  }
}
```

1. Use deconstructing assignment of the payload `{count, rows}`. This makes it clear the properties the payload should have at a glance, and makes them easy to use in the reducer body.
2. Only clone objects once. You have `const clonedState = { ...state }` and also `return { ...clonedState }` where `return clonedState` would do fine (or returning a constructed literal like I have).
3. Don't create local variables for values only used once in the final state. This makes it easier to follow the flow of the reducer.
4. Constructing the whole new state as a single object literal makes it easy to tell what going on and how the data is changing.

This is a somewhat subjective thing, but I think this style has some merit.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks.